# ManualResetEvent.set not getting fired in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

I am working on Visual Web Express 2010. 
I am trying to upload a file to server and block the calling function and release it once uploading is complete. However, the main thread never gets unblocked.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private FileStream fileStream;
    private static String responseStr = "";
    private static ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("App", this);
    }

    public void sendPhoto()
    {
        uploadFile();
    }



    private void uploadFile()
    {
        uploadDataToServer(url);
        evt.WaitOne();
        postProcess();

    }

    public static void postProcess()
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("postProcess2", responseStr);


    }

    void uploadDataToServer(String url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------" + _boundaryNo;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(writeCallback, request);
    }

    private void writeCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        if (memoryStream != null)
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] img = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            postStream.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

        }
    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        streamRead.Close();
        streamResponse.Close();
        response.Close();
        responseStr = responseString;
        evt.Set();

    }


}
```

Now, when I use `evt.WaitOne()` in uploadFile, the whole app goes waiting and no request is send to server, i.e. the code never reaches `getResponseCallBack` and hence the application never wakes up.
However, if I don't use `evt.WaitOne()`, then the request is successful, however I can't read the response text since it's set in `writeCallBack()` function and the request is async one. What should I do to get over this problem?

```
I can't figure out:
1. If the request is multi-threaded / Async, then why evt.WaitOne() makes the complete app waiting and the request doesn't complete?
2. If the request is single threaded, then why postProcess() [removing the evt.WaitOne()] on trying to access responseStr [set in the getResponseCallBack()] doesn't get the proper response set in it.
```

[Sorry, I am new to this and am confused].

Thanks.

Sorry, I forgot to mention one thing that, I am using `silverlight`.

Comment: Remove your `EventHanlde` and move `postProcess` to `writeCallback`.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use the asynchronous calls -- have you tried using just _GetRequestStream() / GetResponseStream()_?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Doing so fires the following error:

Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application This operation can only occur on the UI Thread.   at System.Windows.Hosting.NativeHost.VerifyThread()
   at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.VerifyThreadAndEnabled()
   at System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.get_Window()
   at SimpleFileUpload.MainPage.postProcess()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem that I figured out:

Some have advised to use `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` and make the call synchronous. However, as it seems that silverlight doesn't allow this to take place. Moreover, there was many confusion related to threading and parrallel-processing.

The main problem was that I wasn't able to access the `UI thread` from my callback function, so I used the `dispatcher` method and since it always makes sure that the actions are performed in UI thread, my objective got fulfilled. The following did the trick.

```
System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { postProcess(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in starting an async operation and then waiting for it to complete. Instead of async `request.BeginGetRequestStream(writeCallback, request);` use the synchronous `request.GetRequestStream(...)` and consume it's result. ManualResetEvent would not be needed then.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't seem to find any method definition as request.GetRequestStream(). Though the method seems to be present as per MSDN, but in my version, I can't seem to find it.
Moreover, what I actually want is to show the response to the user, however using HtmlPage.Window.Invoke in GetResponseCallback() throws an error.

Comment: HttpWebRequest's GetRequestStream is definitely there :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx . Make sure that you are casting result of WebRequest.Create(url) to HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I am using .net 4.0.1 version, and there isn't getRequestStream() in it. :(
I am ok with the request being async, however, would like to call js function with my response. Can't seem to do so, that's why wanted to meake it wait and simulate like synchronous one.